# Android Studio : Shutdown Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-15.10

Hi I have recently Ubuntu 15.10 installed in my PC. My PC get shut downs after indexing android studio project. Whenever I create new project or import another project, At the time of indexing my PC get shutdown. I thought it might be memory issue. So I added 8 GB RAM in PC. I had same issue earlier so I formatted My PC. again installed Ubuntu and android studio, still I am facing same problem.

I have also tried to close application which consume much memory and only launched android studio still it shut downs my PC. I am unable to understand how to solve this. This is twice I have reinstalled O.S.

Comment: Your PC could be overheating. You could try checking the CPU temperature when you launch Android Studio.

Comment: After checking CPU temperature. I got this readings  `k10temp-pci-00c3`
`Adapter: PCI adapter`
`temp1:        +77.4°C  (high = +70.0°C)`

Comment: You are using which machine

Comment: AMD sempron Processor and gigabyte board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your `cpu` cooling fan is working properly. Because this could be due to overheating of the `CPU`. For that you can use `lm-sensor` which is availble in `software center` for `temperature sensing`. In addition `Ubuntu 15.10` is not a stable version, it is the `daily build` of `ubuntu`. Try installing the `stable ubuntu` upto now which is `Ubuntu 14.04`. you can download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Choose the `architecture` which fits your computer. If your computer is a new one, sure it is `64bit`. Download `ubuntu 14.04` and once it is finished, before installing `android-studio`, `update` the `operating system` as there are lot of update released for it. Then try installing latest `android-studio` again. it is better if you install `android-studio` in a `linux` based partition which is any partition with `ext4` file format.Try above and let me know what happen.

Comment: First check the CPU temperature using `lm-sensor` at idle state of the system

Comment: once it is installed run `sudo sensors-detect` in `terminal`. Then it will ask your permission to add what it finds to `/etc/modules`. Say 'yes' to all. After it is finished, run `sensors` in `terminal` to get `CPU Temperature`

Comment: `k10temp-pci-00c3`
`Adapter: PCI adapter`
`temp1:        +70.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)` at idle state.

Comment: your `CPU fan `is not working bro, you can see that it is at its max. Check is there any blow from the ventilation if this a laptop

Comment: to make sure that it is overheating  install `psensor` from `software center` it is graphical software so that you can see it easily. and check the temperature mentioned in `physical id` ( it is your CPU). If your temperature rise above `105 C` your processor will die, so immediately replace your `fan` or service your `fan`( Which is not usually done, as replacing is easy)

Comment: I think This might be issue. I feel the heat when I touch outside my cabinet panel.

Comment: At the 3% CPU usage. temperature reaching above 72.0 C

Comment: Sure it is the case, when you run `android-studio` your `processor` gets overheated and to prevent it from `dieing` computer gets shutdown. Replace the fan immediately.

Comment: If you can vote or accept my answer, as I am no longer able post any `questions` here, as I have passed the number of questions that can ask for my current reputation level

Comment: Thanks bro your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi check your RAM slots properly because when 4+4 ram's when you add ,The sharing of memory would be the problem because same thing happened for need check whether to RAM'S belongs to same manufacturer or different check your RAM Usage when opening or creating new project or creating new project.and check your both RAM'S CLOCK SPEED SHOULD BE SAME

Comment: I have one 8 GB of ram. And I tried with creating new small project still shut down my PC.

Comment: can you change your ram and test because happens with memory, its not problem with android studio . else check whether your os any issue u can go with ubuntu 14 LTS .i was using it earlier no worrier with that

Comment: Yup, I will try to install ubuntu 14 LTS. but before some weeks It was working fine.

Comment: hmmm update the results as well looking forward for positive ... cheers :)